# mov dword ptr[eax], 1 is invalid in Hopper Disassembler?

Tags: hopper

I'm trying to Patch a 32bit ELF file with Hopper disassembler

The ASM code I use is like the following

```
mov dword ptr [eax], 15
```

But when I enter that expression, Hopper consider it as invalid? It works perfectly in IDA and I'm not sure why

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: @blabb It's code section. `mov dword ptr ds:[eax], 15` does not work either

Comment: I've just checked Hopper v4 and have no issues with assembling this instruction. There has to be something else. Can you post the binary?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I'm running V3 version .. Guess that's the problem

Comment: @daisy try get in touch with the author. Last few times I contacted him, he was very responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked version v3 and yes, it does not work with such instruction and it does work in v4. There are few [bug reports](https://www.hopperapp.com/bugtracker/index.php?project=1&do=index) that might be related to such issues.

- FS#155
- FS#162

Unfortunately I couldn't find if there is any workaround for this apart from installing a latest one.